# How do I label the x & y axis of multiple graphs on a single graph

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

I have this histograph that shows all my numerical variables. I want to add x and y labels to each of them. Is that possible, or do I have to break them all up into tiny graphs?

```
dfConverted[['attack', 'defense', 'link_number', 'pendulum_left', 'pendulum_right', 'stars']].hist(bins=50, figsize=(20,15))
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting graph]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `hist` method will return a list of axes that you can loop through and update.

```
axes = dfConverted[['attack', 'defense', 'link_number', 'pendulum_left', 'pendulum_right', 'stars']].hist(bins=50, figsize=(20,15)) 
for ax in axes[0]:
  ax.set_xlabel('x')
  ax.set_ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```

Comment: PERFECT! I knew there was something i was missing

Comment: Great! can you please mark this as accepted if it answered your question?